# Make elastic beanstalk ELB listen on port other than 80, 443

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

Is it possible to use the options customization to make the ELB instance created using Elastic beanstalk listen for example on port 8000 ? Tried the following and the instruction seems to be ignored ?

```
Resources:
  AWSEBLoadBalancer:
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer"
    Properties:
      Listeners:
        - {LoadBalancerPort: 8000, InstancePort: 80, Protocol: "HTTPS", SSLCertificateId: "arn:aws:iam::REDACTED"}
```

Comment: Did you open port 8000 on the load balancer security group?

Comment: @GeorgeRushby yes of course. The Listener itself does not get created is the issue.